# Stacked bar chart in QGIS

Tags: qgis, chart, diagram

I have seen several videos of being able to do stacked bars as diagrams to represent atrributes in QGIS (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ras5y6TpECk&ab_channel=WiseGIS) However I do not see stacked bars as an option on my version of QGIS (3.10.6).

Which version was this added/removed?

Answer (score 3):

This feature has been introduced with QGIS 3.12. See: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-new-diagram-type-stacked-bars

Comment: amazing! Thank you